# Is it possible to set SNMP trap/notification target though SNMP?

Tags: snmp

Can I configure trap/notification targets by setting some OID values by sending SNMP SetRequest PDU's ?

Answer (score 1):

If the agent implements it, the standard mechanisms are provided by SNMP-TARGET-MIB (RFC 3413), SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB (also RFC 3413), and (if SNMPv1 or SNMPv2c) SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB (RFC 3584).